# Generating File object that can be read by javascript FileReader without HTML Input tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filereader

I'm a newbie to dynamic HTML websites so bear with me. This is a locally run webpage for my network only. On load of my webpage, I want it to read a text file and place the data into a textarea. This will then update every couple seconds to display the changes in the text file. I've read several examples on how to do it using the input tag in HTML, but I want it to load without user input.

I'd like to use FileReader() with javascript, but don't know how to make an object that can be read by readAsText(object_here).

```
<script>
    var intervalID1;

    function updateTextTimer()
    {
        intervalID1 = setInterval(updateText,5000);
    }

    function updateText()
    {
        var temp = document.getElementById('logOutput');
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var fileName  = "test.txt";

        reader.onload = function(e) {temp.value = e.target.result;}
        reader.readAsText(file_object);
    }   
    </script>
```

Again, I'd prefer to use FileReader because it would be easy, but willing to take suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot read a local file without an user interaction. Please correct me if I'm wrong and I will burn my browser for a security vulnerability

Comment: When you say "locally run website" does it mean you're loading it from the `file://` protocol ? if so, you're stuck for obvious security reasons. However, if you do load it from a local server (`http://localhost`) you can pass the response of a `XMLHttpRequest()` with the `xhr.responseType = "blob"` to your FileReader.

Comment: _"I've read several examples on how to do it using the input tag in HTML, but I want it to load without user input."_ It is not possible to select user files from user filesystem programmically using `input` element . Try using jQuery `.load()` http://api.jquery.com/load to load text file

Comment: Can the OP please clarify. Is your website 1) Running a web server, when you say "local" you mean local to the web sever. 2) Running a webserver, when you say "local" you mean local to the browser (maybe on a another computer on the network). or 3) You double click on an HTML file "local"

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it is on it's own network between a Raspberry Pi and a desktop. The Raspberry Pi will host the website and the desktop will open the website. The data from the text file will dynamically change the format of the website, but I can't seen to load it in without a user prompt

Comment: @Urbanshire if you only need the text content of your txt file hosted on your server, you don't even need a `FileReader` : `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.onload = function(){var textContent = this.responseText; doSomethingWith(textContent);}; xhr.open('GET', 'yourFile.txt'); xhr.send();`

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for the response. As I continue to develop, I keep this in mind. Like I said, I'm a n00b when it comes to dynamic websites. I can HTML for days, but Javascript functionality, currently, eludes my mental grasp.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load)

```
var timeout = null;
(function loadText() {
  $("#logOutput").load("test.txt", function() {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(loadText, 5000)
  })
}())
```

---

e.g.,

```js
var timeout = null, obj = null;
(function loadText() {
  obj = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([$("#input").val()], {
    type: "text/plain"
  }))
  $("#logOutput").load(obj, function() {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(loadText, 5000)
  })
}())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<label for="input">input text here:</label><br />
<textarea id="input">
</textarea>
<br />
<label for="logOutput">output:</label>
<br />
<textarea id="logOutput" disabled>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

`readAsText` Only accept Blob object, you can ref [how to create a Blob OBj](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

Comment: The question is asking how to load a local file, not what parameters to add to the FileReader. @dev-null is right, you can't do it.